# Error with PHP 8.1 MongoDB driver on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: php, mongodb, php-extension, php-mongodb, ubuntu-22.04

(Note: I'm running Ubuntu server 22.04 with PHP 8.1)

I have followed what I assume to be the standard procedure for setting up PHP with MongoDB on Ubuntu systems, that being:

- install `php-fpm`
- install `php-pear`, `php-dev` and `php-mongodb`
- `pecl install mongodb`
- add `extension=mongodb.so` to `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini`
- reload and restart `php8.1-fpm`
- install composer & `composer require mongodb/mongodb` in project root

However, when I run any kind of PHP code that makes use of the MongoDB driver (required with `require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";`); I get the following error: `php: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/php/20210902/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: ns_initparse`.

I have not found anybody else with a similar issue, am I missing some new required step, or should I just drop back down to Ubuntu 20.04 with PHP 7.4 (which works on my development machine running Linux Mint 20.3). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Review the Apache error log. Look for the load of `mongodb.so`. You probably have a dependency that is failing. Edit your question with more details about the load process for `mongodb.so`.

Comment: @JohnHanley It has nothing to do with the web server, even running it simply with the php interpreter gives the same error.

Comment: Wow, you missed my point of looking at the log files for the error cause. It does not matter if you are using the CLI version or the Apache/Nginx version. However, your question is full of details on how you configured it for a web server. If your problem has nothing to do with the web server, remove those details. FYI, the CLI uses different configuration directories.

Comment: I didn't mention a single detail about my web server configuration. My problem is with PHP making use of the MongoDB extension. I detailed exactly what packages I installed, what changes I made to PHP config files and how I required the MongoDB extension in the code.

Comment: What do you think this line applies to: `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini`? FPM is a Fast CGI Process Manager. That means a web server or equivalent.

Comment: I just came across this thread while looking into another `undefined symbol: ns_initparse` report in https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/installing-mongodb-php-driver/193497. I expect this is due to the `configure` script not detecting that `-lresolv` is necessary on Ubuntu 22.04, but I'm still looking into it. I've opened https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHPC-2152 to track this if you'd like to follow that for updates.

Answer (score 1):

I also face this problem, I sovle it following below step

Make sure you has been install php mongodb

```
sudo apt install php8.1-mongodb
```

To do this in Ubuntu, you'll need the php-pear plugin and php-dev

```
sudo apt install php-dev php-pear
```

then you can run:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

then add "extension=mongodb.so" to php.ini

then restart your php service

```
service php8.1-fpm restart
```

or

```
service php-fpm restart
```

Hope can help you!!!

ref : https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php#125027